# Find $1/\sqrt{a}$ with the Newton's method

Tags: sequences-and-series, approximation, newton-raphson

I have sequence defined by :

$$x_{n+1} = x_n - \frac{x_n^{-2} - a} {\frac {-2}{x_n^3}}$$

I need to find the sign of $x_{i+1} - x_i$ for $x_i ∈ ]0, \frac {1}{\sqrt{a}}[ $ and for now i only find this :

$ x_{i+1} - x_i $
$ = $
$ x_i - \frac{x_i^{-2} - a} {\frac {-2}{x_i^3}} - x_i $ 
$ = $
$ - \frac{x_i^{-2} - a} {\frac {-2}{x_i^3}} $
$ = $
$ \frac{x_i^{-2} - a} {\frac {2}{x_i^3}} $
$ = $
$ \frac{x_i - a{x_i^3}} {2} $
$ = $
$ \frac{1} {2} (x_i - a{x_i^3}) $

i don't know if i have to set $a$ to a value and if i can separate the interval.

my questions are, should i set $a$ ? and am i on the right way ?

Comment: what's your question? That seems right? Though it's probably easier to approximate $\sqrt{a}$ instead and reciprocal?

Comment: You may simplify the recursion to $$
x_{n + 1}  = \tfrac{1}{2}x_n (3 - ax_n^2 ).
$$
What does "to analyze" mean in this context?

Comment: @GarethMa: the computation of $1/\sqrt a$ is attractive as it requires no division (which are notoriously slower). In the end you can compute $a\cdot1/\sqrt a$.

Answer (score 1):

In the recursive process

$x_{n+1}=x_{n}-\frac{\frac{1}{x_{n}^{2}}-a} {\frac{-2}{x_{n}^{3}}}$,

starting with $x_{0}=\frac{0.1}{\sqrt{a}}$,

the difference between two successive iterations is always positive and tends to zero;

after a few iterations we arrive at the solution

$x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Notice that the iteration can be written

$$x_{n+1}=\frac12x_n(3-ax_n^2)$$

or

$$\sqrt a x_{n+1}=\frac12\sqrt ax_n(3-(\sqrt ax_n)^2)$$

and with $y:=\sqrt a x_n$,

$$y_{n+1}=\frac12y_n(3-y_n^2).$$

Hence it is enough to consider $a=1$.

Comment: thank you i try this